# Accidentally recursively changed all file permissions in /run (Ubuntu)

Tags: permissions

I have a home server running Myth, Apache, Samba, MySQL etc.

It was late. I was tired. I somehow was one directory level above where I thought I was, and recursively gave the whole world read permissions of `/run`. (Yes, I know...)

I assume that certain files within `/run` are already set up like this, so I don't want to just recursively remove the permission.

As it turns out, I don't have a backup of this folder (something else to fix).

Do I just **leave it**, go for a **full reinstall**, or is there **another option**?

Answer (score 2):

`/run` is of type tmpfs, meaning it exists in memory only, and disappears once the system is powered down. Check this by running `mount` with no arguments, you'll see stuff like:

```
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
```

All files in /run simply contain runtime information for system services and daemons. As long as the permissions for the directory itself (`/run` should have mode 755 and be owned by `root`), you should be able to reboot the system to get a "clean slate". No important data should be lost.